2 strings in 1 element Selenium Python
2 strings in 1 element Selenium Python
I am using Python selenium lib. I am triying to extract both 2 text in one html element. How can I excract them?
I tried "find_element(). I took (div + 7789 div); then .text but this does not work.
Method1

but this does not work <- what is the expected output? What is the observed output? What is the difference between the two? Please edit your post to include this information

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? - Edit your question and share the HTML and code in the form of text.

Your question would be clearer and easier to answer if you had added code examples.
If you want to get the content of an element using Selenium, you can get the element using element = driver.find_element() and once you have the element you can access the text property like: element.text.
#get the webpage 
driver.get("https://mywebsite.site/page.html")

# find element
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div/div')

# print element content
print("The content of the element is: " + element.text)

A working example from a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/github/codesandbox/sandbox-templates/tree/main/python-selenium
